# Event.preventDefault does not seem to work (async context)

Tags: javascript, firefox, error-handling, promise, unhandled-exception

I realise there are a few questions about `preventDefault` not working. But my question is about the rather straightforward case where you have an `async` function and an error is thrown:

```
throw 'error of some kind';
```

... and then you want to have a "mopping up" function to catch any and all such errors. This then works as expected:

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function (event) {
    console.log( 'unhandled Promise rejection, event: ', event );

    // event.preventDefault();
});
```

But if I uncomment the `event.preventDefault()`, I expect to see the `throw` message not then get printed as an error to console. But it always does get so printed.

I checked to make sure that `event` is indeed `cancelable` in this case. It claims to be so.

PS from my experiments it seems to be that

```
window.onunhandledrejection = event => {
    ...
};
```

is just another way of implementing this same listener for this same "unhandledrejection" event. Using `event.preventDefault()` there doesn't seem to work either.

**Edit**

After a few experiments I seem to find that the only way I can find to prevent this is to swallow the error (using `try...catch`) at some point, preferably at the highest `async` call in the stack (or rather in the sequence of calls of `async` functions), if that can be determined.

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
  console.log(event.cancelable, event.reason, "unhandled rejection")
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  return false
})

async function x() {
  console.log('async')
  throw "async error"
}

x()

new Promise(res => {
  console.log('prom')
  throw "prom error"
})
```

Comment: under which browser?  works for me under Chrome 81.  Post a runnable stack snippet that shows what you mean.  note errors like syntax errors are language level, and are not thrown at runtime and so aren't caught

Comment: Thanks. Firefox 72. I'll try to get a snippet out reasonably soon.  This is a regular `throw` + string message, as shown above.

Comment: Verified on Firefox 76.  Straight Promises don't work either.  Looks like a bug.  Probably should file an issue with Firefox tracker.

Comment: Thanks ... but could you possibly remove that snippet and maybe put it in an answer? Then it could be discussed as an answer.  I just tried those propagation commands, and `return false`: nothing seems to work in FF72 anyway.

Comment: I added those in just to show that preventing bubbling doesn't help.  Pretty sure it's just not implemented yet and should be filed as a bug with Mozilla.  You've found a bug I think.

Comment: I reported this as a bug in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1642147

Comment: Note that the propagation is correctly stopped: https://jsfiddle.net/udfwe823/ Only the default behavior of logging the error is not prevented.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the fiddle demonstration, useful to know. Is it official that event listeners get fired in the order in which they appear in the code, I wonder? (Not that this makes any difference to the validity of your observation).

Comment: Since here there will not be any bubblong (because the event fires on window) yes, it's specced behavior

Comment: FWIW, in Chrome 92 on Linux it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @balu did you try running the code snippet? It works fine in Chromium 94 on Linux, but it doesn't work in the console because chrome [is ridiculously strict about cross-origin policy](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=655694) and the devtools cross an origin boundary.

Comment: @Masklinn Huh. Indeed, I tried again and `event.preventDefault()` seems to successfully prevent the error from getting printed to the console in Chrome 92. No idea what I did wrong the first time.

Comment: @balu I mentioned the console because that's exactly the issue I had in trying it: if you copy the code to the developer tools console it will silently fail because of COP restrictions. If you run it as part of a page it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Verified on Firefox 76. Straight Promises don't work either. Looks like a bug. Probably should file an issue with Mozilla's Firefox tracker.
Note: this is not a solution. It's doubtful there is any solution except filing a bug and having it fixed.

```js
window.onerror = msg => console.log(msg) || false

window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
  console.log(event.cancelable, event.reason, "unhandled rejection")
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  return false
})

async function x() {
  console.log('async')
  throw "async error"
}

x()

new Promise(res => {
  console.log('prom')
  throw "prom error"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. As I said, neither "stop propagation" commands seems to work, nor returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Repro on Firefox97. It seems the error logs were printed on the console before triggering the `'unhandledrejection'` handler so the `event.preventDefault()` could not help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31209797)