# Handling Mapbox autofill Error: suggestion is required

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using [Mapbox autofill](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/autofill/). When a user types some address that doesn't exist like in the picture.
[image]

Then he clicks enter to autofill the full address with the suggestion. The suggestion this way is undefined and error will be thrown:

[image]

Uncaught (in promise) Error: suggestion is required.

Through debugging I found this is the place where error happens.
[image]

I would like to handle it so I could provide the user with some toast message/notification asking him to fill whole address. Leaving it just in the console would be ugly.

I know that [there are 3 events](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/autofill/#autofillcollection-events) that come from autobox and can be handled through eventlistener.

None of them is triggered if the aforementioned error is thrown, even when I was expecting that at least on 'suggesterror'.

Any ideas on how I can catch this error? It seems to be visible in console even on [the official example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/example/autofill-checkout-js/) as they are not handling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapbox dev here - we have made a fix that will be included in the next release (coming soon!) of Search JS that will remove this console error.

If you want to toast/notify the end-user to fill out all fields, I recommend moving that into form pre-submission validation.

EDIT: this issue has been fixed in v1.0.0-beta.14

Comment: Ok, I wait for the next release then. In the meantime solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have found a solution. Still, I think it's not as clean as its global error handler.

```
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (event) => { });
```

[Also it doesn't prevent printing to console on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62100577/event-preventdefault-does-not-seem-to-work-async-context).